# Please suggest the best way to design my database

Tags: database, database-design

I have a table named `Pages` and a table named `Categories`. Each entry of the table `Pages` is linked to the table `Categories`. The `Categories` table has 5 entries, they are: `Car`, `Websites`, `Technology`, `Mobile Phones`, and `Interest`.

So each time I put an entry to the `Pages` table, I need to map it to the `Categories` table so are arranged properly.

Here's my table:

**Pages**

```
id [PK]
name
url
```

**Categories**

```
id [PK]
Categoryname
```

**Pages2Categories**

```
Pages.id
Categories.id
```

So my question is, is this the most efficient way to create this kind of relationships between tables? It seems very amateur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each page must have exactly 1 category, put the category ID in table Pages.

If each page optionally have one category and most pages does not have one, put the (page_id, category_id) in a separate table with primary key(page_id)

If each page may have several categories, use the approach you suggested.

Don't worry about space or performance at this point.

Comment: Ronnis, should I put the categoryID in the Pages table as a primary key?

Comment: @Raymond, Page_id would be the primary key in Pages? [Pages.CategoryID] should be a foreign key to [categories.ID].

Answer (score 1):

Since ¨category¨ is an attribute of a ¨page¨, it is best to keep that attribute in the ¨pages¨ table. To save space, you could use an integer/number data type for the ¨category¨ column. e.g 1 = Car, 2 = Websites, 3 = Technology and so forth.

Comment: I read about database normalization and it suggests that when creating tables, we need to avoid multiple data entries. So I created the category tables to put all the categories there and just link it..

Comment: @Raymond Using Viren's method you would still need another table to map the numbers to a category type; otherwise you will need to do this in your code through the use of an enum possibly, which I wouldn't recommend. I am not sure which of the above two options Viren is recommending, but Ronnis's answer sums up your options pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion: Have 2 tables - "pages" and "category". Columns in pages are:

Name [varchar]
URL [varchar]
Category [tinyint]

For Category, as you designed:

catID [1|2|4|8|16] (5 possible values for 5 categories)
catName [varchar]

I assume you have a small # of categories (<8), if this count goes upto 31, use an integer instead (using 4 instead of 1 byte per row). Now Category in the pages table need not be an FK to the other table. You could do a logical OR for insert/update and AND for select in your jdbc code if an URL belongs to more than 1 category. May not be the best DB design, but this should minimize the db-Space you consume, in case you have to save millions of pages. From your problem statement, I do not see why you need a PK in the table... eliminate it to save a few more bytes in every row. Regards, - M.S.